# Deleting files based on the contents of the file in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, grepl

I have hundreds of .xlsx files that have the same structure. Some of the files in this folder are from an outdated structure that I do not use anymore. I am trying to apply a function to the files I want, while removing the ones I no longer want. I am trying to delete all of the files where the first column in the file contains the string `"Prices"`. This never occurs in the new files (the ones I want to keep), and if it does not contain the `"Prices"` string, it will continue to use a function
I have created to assign the wrangled data into a new list.

I have a for-loop that looks like so:

```
estimates_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(list.files(".")) # list I created
new_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(list.files("."))

for(i in 1:length(list.files("."))){
  estimates_list[[i]] <- read_excel(list.files(".")[i], col_names = F) #reads in all of the files to a list

  if(grepl("^Prices", estimates_list[[i]][,1])){ 

    file.remove(list.files(".")[i])

 } else{ 

   new_list[[i]] <- test_function(estimates_list[[i]])

 }
}
```

Everything works just as I want it to, except when the loop gets to a file where the `grepl("^Prices", estimates_list[[i]][,1])` is `TRUE` at any point in the first column, the file file does not get deleted.

To give an example, Let's say I run `grepl("^Prices", estimates_list[[1]][,1])`, then it will output  a vector of `FALSE FALSE ... FALSE FLASE`. Everything is `FALSE`, so I want it to then apply the function in the `else` statement.

Now, if I run `grepl("^Prices", estimates_list[[24]][,1])`, then I get a vector of `TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE`. I want this file to be deleted and the loop to continue down the list of files until the end of the estimate_list object. I want to note that the `"Prices"` string does vary throughout the first column across all files.

Comment: try `any(grepl("^Prices", estimates_list[[i]][,1]))` in if()

Comment: I still get an error that pertains to the function because the function only works with the appropriate files. I am confused because the loop works just fine for the appropriate files, but when the loop runs into a file I want to delete, it ignores the if statement and tries to apply the function to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following will work.

The code below does not create the two list in the `for` loop. In fact, it only creates `new_list` and only after the `for` loop. In the loop it uses a cells range spec output by `cellranger::cell_limits` to read only the 1st column and deletes the file if the regex pattern `"^Prices"` is found in the read in column.

Then, after updating the files vector `fls`, it reads in the files that were not deleted and processes them in two `lapply` loops. Processing is protected by `tryCatch`. Errors, if any, are put in an errors list `err_list` and `new_list` is the good data list.

I believe that like this it is simpler to detect errors.

```
fls <- list.files(".", full.names = TRUE)
first_col <- cellranger::cell_limits(c(1, 1), c(NA, 1))
for(i in 1:length(fls)){
  estimates_sheet <- readxl::read_excel(
    path = fls[i], 
    range = first_col,
    col_names = FALSE
  )
  if(any(grepl("^Prices", estimates_sheet[[1]]))){ 
    file.remove(fls[i])
  }
}

fls <- list.files(".", full.names = TRUE)
new_list <- lapply(fls, read_excel, col_names = FALSE)

new_list <- lapply(new_list, \(xl) {
  tryCatch(test_function(xl), error = function(e) e)
})
err <- sapply(new_list, inherits, "error")
err_list <- new_list[err]
new_list <- new_list[!err]
```